# ElasticSearch: Sort aggregation key in case-insensitive and remain the case of the key

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get distinct make value from car and the make values should sort case-insensitively in ascending order. I am using elasticsearch version 2.4.4

Mapping for color and make field

```
      "color": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "lcsort": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
          }
        }
      },
      "make": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "lcsort": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
          }
        }
      }
```

My settings on case_insensitive_sort analyzer

```
 "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
```

Query 1

```
{
"size" : 0,
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match" : {
                "color" : "red"
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs" : {
    "distinct_makes" : {
        "terms" : {
            "size" : 20,
            "field" : "make.keyword",
            "order" : {
                "_term" : "asc"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Result I get from Query 1

```
 "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "Audi",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "BMW",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Ferrari",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Honda",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Hyundai",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Lexus",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "acura",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "bentley",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
```

I change the query to use make.lcsort field

```
{
"size" : 0,
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match" : {
                "color" : "red"
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs" : {
    "distinct_makes" : {
        "terms" : {
            "size" : 10000,
            "field" : "make.lcsort",
            "order" : {
                "_term" : "asc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get all buckets sort in correct but all the keys become lowercase

```
 "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "acura",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "audi",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "bentley",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "bmw",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "ferrari",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "honda",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "hyundai",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "lexus",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
```

My expected result will be

```
 "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "acura",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Audi",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "bentley",
      "doc_count": 1
    },{
"key": "BMW",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
    {
      "key": "Ferrari",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Honda",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Hyundai",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Lexus",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
```

Is it possible for term aggregation to return the case of indexed data, and sort them in case-incentive way?

Comment: Can you show how your `case_insensitive_sort` analyzer looks like ?

Comment: `code` "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "case_insensitive_sort": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }

Comment: Have the same issue. Also asked here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-case-insensitive-sort-on-keyword-aggregation/268198